# How to run corr.test efficiently on two bigmatrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, psych

I have two matrices and each contain 300 rows and 40k columns.
I am trying to find correlation (using corr.test from "psych" - R package)between these two as defined in the below examples a and b. 
Is there anyway I can make corr.test run much faster ?

```
library(bigmemory)

library(psych)

a<-read.big.matrix("a.matrix.t", head=T, sep='\t', type="char")

b<-read.big.matrix("b.matrix.t", head=T, sep='\t', type="char")

z <- corr.test(a[], b[], use = "pairwise", method = "pearson", ci=F)

c <- as.big.matrix(z$r)

p <- as.big.matrix(z$p)

write.big.matrix(c, "correlations.txt", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE)

write.big.matrix(p, "adj.pvalues.txt", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE)
```

example files:

```
> a

     r1    r2    r3
s1    1    1    4
s2    2    2    6
s3    3    3    9
s4    4    4   12
s5    5    5    6

> b

     g1    g2    g3
s1    6    5    7
s2    7    4    4
s3    8    3    3
s4    9    2    3
s5   10    1    9

> corr.test(a,b)

           cor      adj-pvalue
r1,g1  1.0000000    0.00000001
r2,g2  1.0000000    0.00000007
r3,g3  0.5050763    0.00006986
```

Comment: this package is written in pure R. Perhaps you are looking to write [this function](https://github.com/cran/psych/blob/master/R/corr.test.R) with Rcpp?

Comment: try data.table, format convert to data.table and check the time of run.

Comment: Perhaps [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/bigcor-large-correlation-matrices-in-r/) on rblogger can help you. In brief, break down your matrix in blocks using the ff package, then run `cor()`  function (Hmisc package) on each block. Or the `rcorr()` for the pvalue.

Comment: @shayaa: I am getting the follwoing error when I run Rcpp function - `could not find function "fisherz" `

Comment: `fisherz` is another function in the `psych` package. I sent you a link to the github mirror, but you can always see the source of a function with `getAnywhere(function_name)`

Comment: @Jimbou: In the link that you suggested cor() or rocrr() do not take two matrices as input but just one.